# extracting corresponding values from lists in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a very simple data frame ("newDF") consisting of 2 lists "year" and "value". The list "year" is a simple list from 1850 to 2011. I wish to extract the "value" corresponding to the year 1990 for use in another package. I suspect it is a very simple question. Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: can you post code so we can see exactly what the newDf looks like? do you mean it has 2 columns? how about newDf[newDf$year == 1990, "value"]?

Comment: not sure why this was down-voted.  The question is rather clear.

Comment: 1) no code so we can see whats going on. 2) if it really is asking what it sounds like, this is a question that is easily answered by reading any tutorial on r

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
newDF$value[newDF$year==1990]
```

The `$` identifies a column in the dataframe; the brackets are a way to subset that column, and inside the brackets you just put a logical argument that will be (TRUE) for the row (or rows) you want. So you could get all years since 1990 with a very simply modification:

```
newDF$value[newDF$year>=1990]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
subset(newDF, year==1990, select="value")
```

Comment: True, the quotes are not needed. Can also be an expression vector like: c(value1, value2)